# How can I remove spaces from link with get parameter?

Tags: php

I just created a php application which allows the creation of a personal christmas e-card. The user can enter a custom text and after he has checked the text and has clicked the green button, a link with a get parameter is generated for him. This link he can use to put in e-mails and send it to his friends and family.

My problem is that the chars in the get-parameter **(= ?botschaft)** do not appear in one line, not one after another. Everytime there was a line break in the text, there is also a break in the link which just looks ugly. Here is an example of a link that works:

```
http://www.christian-kress.net/koelsche_weihnachtskarte/index.php?botschaft=This is an e-card I generated with my application.<br />
<br />
My problem is that the chars in the link do not appear one after another, but<br />
there are spaces when there is a new line.
```

I used the nl2br-function in order to make sure that the br-Tags are in the link and that line breaks will be shown when the user clicks on the link and looks up the christmas message. But now I want to remove the spaces. It shall all appear in one single stringent line!

Can anyone help? Does anyone know a suitable (string) function to achieve that?

So just to make it clear, the desired output of the link above would be something like this:

```
http://www.christian-kress.net/koelsche_weihnachtskarte/index.php?botschaft=This_is_an
e-card_I_generated_with_my_application.<br/><br/>My_problem_is_that_the_chars_in_the_link_do_not_appear_one_after_another,_but_there_are_spaces_when_there_is_a_new_line.
```

How can I add the underline-sign and how can I make sure that when the user enters the link and the message is being constructed and shown based on the parameter's content that the underline-signs will not appear?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Christian

Answer (score 0):

The right way would be to encode that URL using the `urlencode` function.

You could also just replace spaces with underscore:

```
echo str_replace(' ', '_',"http://www.christian-kress.net/koelsche_weihnachtskarte/index.php?botschaft=This is an e-card I generated with my application.<br />");
```

Prints:

> http://www.christian-kress.net/koelsche_weihnachtskarte/index.php?botschaft=This_is_an_e-card_I_generated_with_my_application.

Comment: You shouldn't use `urlencode` on the whole url, as it encodes all special characters like `[:/?]` etc which renders the link useless if it contains a `http://` or the like. You must use `rawurlencode` on everything before get symbol `?` and `urlencode` on everything after `?`

Comment: @gwillie yup you are right. I guess I was not paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

Just warp the output of the link in `urlencode();`. It converts all nasty characters like whitespaces.